# How import csv data in php mysql database with if else condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

I need to import csv data in database where my Product table have two columns code and price. I am importing data with this script, which find the product code and then update that product price -

```
function update_price()
{
    $this->sma->checkPermissions('csv');
    $this->load->helper('security');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', lang("upload_file"), 'xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {



        if (isset($_FILES["userfile"])) {

            $this->load->library('upload');

            $config['upload_path'] = $this->digital_upload_path;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
            $config['max_size'] = $this->allowed_file_size;
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
                redirect("products/update_price");
            }

            $csv = $this->upload->file_name;

            $arrResult = array();
            $handle = fopen($this->digital_upload_path . $csv, "r");
            if ($handle) {
                while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $arrResult[] = $row;
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
            $titles = array_shift($arrResult);

            $keys = array('code', 'price');

            $final = array();

            foreach ($arrResult as $key => $value) {
                $final[] = array_combine($keys, $value);
            }
            $rw = 2;
            foreach ($final as $csv_pr) {
                if (!$this->products_model->getProductByCode(trim($csv_pr['code']))) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang("check_product_code") . " (" . $csv_pr['code'] . "). " . lang("code_x_exist") . " " . lang("line_no") . " " . $rw);
                    redirect("product/update_price");
                }
                $rw++;
            }
        }

    }

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && !empty($final)) {
        $this->products_model->updatePrice($final);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang("price_updated"));
        redirect('products');
    } else {

        $this->data['error'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('error'));

        $this->data['userfile'] = array('name' => 'userfile',
            'id' => 'userfile',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('userfile')
        );

        $bc = array(array('link' => base_url(), 'page' => lang('home')), array('link' => site_url('products'), 'page' => lang('products')), array('link' => '#', 'page' => lang('update_price_csv')));
        $meta = array('page_title' => lang('update_price_csv'), 'bc' => $bc);
        $this->page_construct('products/update_price', $meta, $this->data);

    }
}
```

But here our product price update and replace old value , but i want check old value of price and 
if old value is greater than uploaded value  , then not replaced and 
if old value is lower than uploaded value of price then update/replaced that value . 
means in all condition our price is always maximum .
how we can do it ??? anyone help please ..

Comment: are anyone cannot help me here ????please give hint ...any hint

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look inside the `updatePrice` method and modify a mysql query in it.

Mysql has a proper `Update if` statement.

Comment: but how it check value is greater or lower

Comment: look the specification or real examples